# Pegar o value do select

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

Meu Select está assim:

```
<select class="input-medium ajuste" id="sel_mes">
  <option value="09/03/2014">Março - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/04/2014">Abril - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/05/2014">Maio - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/06/2014">Junho - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/12/2015">Dezembro - 2015</option>
  <option value="09/01/2016">Janeiro - 2016</option>
</select>
```

Quero pegar o value, ou seja a data `09/04/2014` e não o texto `Abril - 2014`

Estou utilizando este:

```
var ValorA = $("#sel_mes").val();
```

Já tentei este tambpém

```
var ValorA = $("#sel_mes option:selected").val();
```

Porém ambos retornam `Abril - 2014`

Colote via JQuery Assim

```
        function montaMeses(data){
        $.ajax({
           async: false,     
           type: "POST",
           url: "../execs/proc_fluxocaixa.php",
           data: {d_acao: "meses", c_data: data},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(ret_dados){                         
               $("#sel_mes").html(ret_dados.meses);
           }                               
        });            
    }
```

NO PHP

```
function MesExt($mes){
    if ($mes == 1) {return "Janeiro";};
    if ($mes == 2) {return "Fevereiro";};
    if ($mes == 3) {return utf8_encode("Março");};
    if ($mes == 4) {return "Abril";};
    if ($mes == 5) {return "Maio";};
    if ($mes == 6) {return "Junho";};
    if ($mes == 7) {return "Julho";};
    if ($mes == 8) {return "Agosto";};
    if ($mes == 9) {return "Setembro";};
    if ($mes == 10){return "Outubro";};
    if ($mes == 11){return "Novembro";};
    if ($mes == 12){return "Dezembro";};
}

if($acao == "meses"){
    $optMeses = "";
    $atual = $_POST["c_data"];
    $Data = explode("/", $atual);

    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 12, 0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 12, 0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 11, 0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 11, 0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 10, 0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 10, 0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 9,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 9,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 8,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 8,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 7,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 7,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 6,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 6,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 5,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 5,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 4,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 4,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 3,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 3,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 2,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 2,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 1,  0, false)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 1,  0, false) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";

    $a1 = explode("/", $atual); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value'$atual' selected>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";

    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 1,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 1,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 2,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 2,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 3,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 3,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 4,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 4,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 5,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 5,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 6,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 6,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 7,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 7,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 8,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 8,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 9,   0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 9,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 10,  0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 10,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 11,  0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 11,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";
    $a1 = explode("/", $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 12,  0, true)); $MesExtenso = MesExt($a1[1]); $AnoExtenso = $a1[2]; $optMeses .= "<option value='" . $Sv->somar_data($atual, 0, 12,  0, true) . "'>$MesExtenso - $AnoExtenso</option>";

    $retorno["meses"] = $optMeses;
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o html do seu select?

Comment: <select class="input-medium ajuste" name="sel_conta" id="sel_conta"></select>, porém é alimentado via jquery. Mas está alimentando certo.

Comment: `$("#sel_mes option:selected").val();` funciona da forma esperada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode pegar o valor do item selecionado no é usando a função [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) no próprio `select`.

Veja funcionando:

```js
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert($('#sel_mes').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input-medium ajuste" id="sel_mes">
  <option value="09/03/2014">Março - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/04/2014">Abril - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/05/2014">Maio - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/06/2014">Junho - 2014</option>
  <option value="09/12/2015">Dezembro - 2015</option>
  <option value="09/01/2016">Janeiro - 2016</option>
</select>

<button>Valor</button>
```

Comment: Deve ser outro trecho do meu código que esta gerando algum erro, pois tenho exatamente assim. Coleto de um combo ao lado e funciona irei analisar novamente.

Comment: @JoelHenriqueRother Edite sua pergunta e adicione esse trecho do seu código completo.

Comment: @JoelHenriqueRother Achou o problema? Se puder depois deixe um comentário informando o que estava causando o erro.

Comment: Não achei, mas como estou alimentando uma variável no retorno estou utilizando ela e da certo, meio sem tempo para ver o que poderia gerar pois o código é simples, estranho isso. No fim deve ser uma virgula ou erro no código a gente sempre encontra, deixei para um segundo plano, agradeço

Comment: sou novo aqui, não sei pode trocar contatos. Mas se puder tem skype?

Answer (score 3):

Usando javascript simples:

```js
var ValorA = document.getElementById("sel_mes").value
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET

```
alert($('#cod_unidademedida').val());

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Unidade de Medida", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownList("cod_unidademedida", null, "--Selecione--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cod_unidademedida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```